# My website refreshes everytime I run my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#form").toggle();
  });
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($(".product").checked = true) {
      alert("Thank You!")
    } else {
      alert('Please Choose A Product');
    }
  var name = $("input:text").val();
  var nLi = $("<li>").appendTo("ul");
  nLi.text(name);
  });
});
```

Everytime I put text in the text input, the `<li>` will display for only a moment, but the page will refresh and it will disappear. Sorry if this is obvious, I'm still learning.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide more details

Comment: Please post more of your code.

Comment: Is it disappearing after you press the submit button?

Comment: @KevBot The li will show for one second then dissapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't allow the page to refresh. Return false at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#form").toggle();
  });
  $("#submit").click(function() {
        if ($(".product").checked) {
          alert("Thank You!")
        } else {
          alert('Please Choose A Product');
        }
      var name = $("input:text").val();

      var nLi = $("<li>").appendTo("ul");
      nLi.text(name);

      return false;

  });
});
```

And please change
        `if ($(".product").checked = true) {`

to 
         `if ($(".product").checked == true) {`

Comment: While I broadly agree, `$(".product").checked == true` shouldn't work, given that –so far as I know – a jQuery Object doesn't have `checked` property. And, if it does, it will only retrieve the property from the first element held in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use event.preventDefault() in your click event, for example:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

for more info about this jquery method [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)